# Javascript Fails to add href

Tags: javascript, html, href

The script in this code should create a href link, but it doesn't:

```
  <script>
     document.getElementById('linkid').href='www.wikipedia.org';
     </script>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Href test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Href test</h1>
    <a id='linkid'>Link for wikipedia</a>
    <table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You have no `#linkid` element.

Comment: thanks for the link. solution:

Comment: <script>
 window.onload = ()=>{
 document.getElementById('linkid').href='www.wikipedia.org';
}
 </script>

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/Rakesh029/qcaj7po4/3/